# Is it possible that Madara could have used the Izanagi after his "death"?

Tags: naruto

When he was defeated by Hashirama, he put a one-day time lapsed Izanagi on himself. When Kaguya is defeated and Madara is spat out by her unstable transformation, we see him supposedly die in front of everybody. I don't think it was ever shown what happened to his body, and nobody ever took his Sharingan.

Is it possible he could have put another Izanagi on himself and be still alive, or put a very long-lasting time lapse on himself (70 years for instance), so when he is brought back Naruto and Sasuke will be gone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we don't know what happened to his body, we are almost sure that his death this time was in absolute certainty.

First, only a Sharingan can cast the Izanami (taken from the [Naruto wikia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanagi?oldid=1224403)):

> Izanagi can be used only by those with the genetic traits of the Sage of Six
> Paths. The Uchiha, descended from the Sage, are able to perform Izanagi with
> their Sharingan. Even with such an eye acting as a medium, gaining the power
> to temporarily control reality's flow as the user sees fit comes at a price;
> one has very limited reserves of time within a single eye for invoking this
> technique. This technique would normally be used for only the most dire of
> situations and for but a brief moment as after the Sharingan with which
> Izanagi was casted exceeds its limit, the said eye becomes powerless and is
> rendered blind permanently, with the rare exception that its sight and power
> can be restored to the said eye by further evolving it into a Rinnegan.

Madara could switch between both the Sharingan and the Rinnegan effortlessly. But there is one thing we know for certain and that is when a Tailed Beast extraction occurs the *jinchuuriki* faces certain death. When we saw that Kaguya had burst out from Madara we saw something similar happen, and the beast was extracted from him into Kaguya and wasn't spit out until later when Kaguya was about to be defeated. Madara was ultimately out of chakra and he couldn't even switch between the eyes at the end as we could see. If he didn't have the Tailed Beasts extracted maybe he could have.

There is another argument I have: after Madara became the Sage of Six Paths, I think Madara could no longer access the *dojutsu* powers of his Sharingan. But this is only mere speculation.

Comment: No Juubi Jinchuriki dies from the Juubi being extracted because it has a shell, the same shell Hagoromo used to form the moon. It's just that they cannot move for a long period of time (a few months I believe) and cannot be healed unless someone uses a jutsu like Creation of all Things, where you add life to nothing. (which is why obito was well after juubi was extracted)

Comment: But that speculation is most likely correct, as Obito could no longer use Kamui or any form of Mangekyou Sharingan abilities. In Madara's case it seemed like whatever eye he had active when become Juubi Jinchuriki (Rinnegan) is what he sticks with. Though after being spit out by Kaguya his chakra was so low his Rinnegan auto-deactivated into a base Sharingan.

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that Izanagi should be active before the scene occurred and it only lasts for a while, so any surprise attacks or ambush attacks will definitely work on them.

Second thing is that he doesn't have Sharingan while dying he has Rinnegan remember, so after he separated from Kaguya he has normal eyes I guess.

And third thing is that it went all according to plan except for Kaguya, so he was not prepared for this and took him by surprise.

Comment: Does having a rinnegan really limit the use of Izanagi? I believe a Rinnegan user like Madara and Sasuke would still be able to perform Izanagi because their rinnegans still allow them to use Susano'o (for which you need 2 MS). Why would one sharingan ability still be available and the other not?

Comment: He does have a Sharingan while he was dying, it was literally activated when Hashirama talked to him in the end lol